# Robots.txt and sub-folders

Tags: seo, robots.txt

Several domains are configured as add-ons to my primary hosting account (shared hosting).

The directory structure looks like this (primary domain is example.com):

- public_html (example.com)
- _sub
- - ex1 --> displayed as example-realtor.com
- - ex2 --> displayed as example-author.com
- - ex3 --> displayed as example-blogger.com

*(the SO requirement to use `example` as the domain makes explanation more difficult - for example, sub ex1 might point to plutorealty and ex2 might point to amazon, or some other business sub-hosting with me.  The point is that each ex# is a different company's website, so mentally substitute something normal and different for each "example")*

Because these domains (ex1, ex2, etc) are add-on domains, they are accessible in two ways *(ideally, the 2nd method is known only to me)*:

(1) http://example1.com
(2) http://example.com/_sub/ex1/index.php

*Again, `example1.com` is a totally unrelated website/domain name from `example.com`*

QUESTIONS:

(a) How will the site be indexed on search engines?  Will both (1) and (2) show up in search results? *It is undesireable for method 2 to show up in google)*

(b) Should I put a robots.txt in `public_html` that disallows each folder in the _sub folder?  Eg:

```
 User-agent: *
 Disallow: /_sub/
 Disallow: /_sub/ex1/
 Disallow: /_sub/ex2/
 Disallow: /_sub/ex3/
```

(c) Is there a more common way to configure add-on domains?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about seo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This robots.txt would be sufficient, you don’t have to list anything that comes after `/_sub/`:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /_sub/
```

This would disallow bots (who honor the robots.txt) to crawl any URL whose path starts with `/_sub/`. But that doesn’t necessarily stop these bots to index your URL itself (e.g., list them in their search results).

Ideally you would redirect from `http://example.com/_sub/ex1/` to `http://example1.com/` with [HTTP status code 301](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301). It depends on your server how that works (for Apache, you could use a `.htaccess`). Then everyone ends up on the canonical URL for your site.

Comment: Thanks for this. I still do not fully understand: if I `Disallow: /_sub/` will the domain associated with this folder also be disallowed? (Not the main domain for the hosting account, but the specific domain that points only to this folder -- the one set up as a subdomain on the hosting account) I updated the original question to highlight the issue of the multiple domains associated with one hosting account.

Comment: @crashwap: The robots.txt is always for the host it’s accessible from. So for `http://example.com/_sub/ex1/index.php`, bots will look at `http://example.com/robots.txt` for the robots.txt (which is what you want), and for `http://example1.com/` they will look at `http://example1.com/robots.txt` (which wouldn’t harm, unless you also have URLs starting with `/_sub/` there). -- Note that you don’t have to fiddle with robots.txt if you go with the preferred way to redirect to the canonical URL.

Comment: So, **(1)** if I disallow `/_sub/ex1/` on example.com, that will not effect ex1-realtor.com when googlebot scans *that* domain *(in a situation where ex1-realtor.com points to example.com/_sub/ex1 folder)*  and **(2)** only ex1-realtor.com will be displayed in the google results (i.e. `example.com/_sub/ex1` will not also be displayed?

Comment: @crashwap: If there is no robots.txt in the folder `/_sub/ex1/`, nothing is blocked for `ex1-realtor.com`. -- As I described in my anwer, Google might still show the URLs from `example.com/_sub/ex1` in their SERPs (if they somehow happen to find them), but they may not crawl (i.e., visit) them. Robots.txt can stop crawling of documents, not indexing of URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Do not Use Multi site features with Google. Google Ranking effect on Main domain also. If Black hat and also Spam generate sub directory sites.

My Suggestion If you need important site on Sub Categories then Put all Sub Domain noindex .

> Robot.txt

```
User-agent: *
 Disallow: /_sub/
 Disallow: /_sub/ex1/
 Disallow: /_sub/ex2/
 Disallow: /_sub/ex3/
```